# React-bootstrap code not rendering

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have installed react-bootstrap with npm (npm install react-bootstrap --save) but my code is not rendering on the browser. The page is just blank. I use webpack for builds and babel for transpilation. Below is my react code.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap'

const buttonsInstance = (
  <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" active>Primary button</Button>
    <Button bsSize="large" active>Button</Button>
  </ButtonToolbar>
);

ReactDOM.render(buttonsInstance, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the controls you'll use explicitly:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {ButtonToolbar, Button} from 'react-bootstrap' // define individual controls to import    
const buttonsInstance = (
  <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" active>Primary button</Button>
    <Button bsSize="large" active>Button</Button>
  </ButtonToolbar>
);

ReactDOM.render(buttonsInstance, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Good job Johnny. If you're unfamiliar with import syntax here (i.e. using curly brackets {} ) then checkout Destructuring.

Comment: How exactly will i apply that??

Comment: Well it's just FYI - ES6 destructuring if you want to understand what  {Button} actually means. It won't affect your example but might make you a better dev!

Comment: Tried something like this:                                                                      import {ButtonToolbar: BtnBar, Button: Btn} from 'react-bootstrap'                                and substituted them in their respective tags but did not work. Maybe i am not doing it properly.

Comment: Try `import { Button as Btn } from 'react-bootstrap'. Your syntax is correct for es6 objects in general but when importing try the aforementioned if you want to use aliases. Checkout [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)